# Embedded video shows a totally other video

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, video, youtube, embed

I tried embedding a video using bootstrap but on the website instead of showing the video that I linked, it shows a different playlist.

```html
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
      
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2vQV8UnfjHI"></iframe>

</div>
```

However instead of playing the video when I open the webpage my "Favorites" playlist from youtube is instead played. Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Answer (score 0):

try clear browser cache or reload page with ctrl+F5